# Set text color to top bar right buttons in overflow menu using react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, android-titlebar, overflow-menu

I am trying to add right menus to the top bar in the form of overflow menu by setting the flag "showAsAction" to "never". The buttons are seen as expected in a popup, but in black text color. I need the text in blue color with an icon to the left. Please help to achieve this. Note : If "showAsAction" is set to always, the blue color is applied. I am using react-native-navigation

```
rightButtons: [
      {
        id: 'menu_one',
        text: 'One',
        icon: require('./icon1.png'),
        disableIconTint: false,
        systemItem: 'done',
        showAsAction: 'never',
        color:'#d73232',
      },
      {
        id: 'menu_two',
        text: 'Two',
        color:'#d73232',
        showAsAction: 'never',
        icon: require('./icon2.png'),
        enabled: true
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Show me the applied screen shot and the code part.